# PHPspreedsheet, Cómo leer datos de un JSON en MySQL para una hoja de calculo

Tags: php, mysql, json, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

Tengo el sig. JSON que se toma directamente de una tabla en MYSQL

```
 {
    "dispositivo_correcto_seg\u00fan_n\u00famero_de_parte#Dispositivo_de_ensamble_(Bloques)": "ok",
    "dispositivo_limpio_sin_manchas_de_pintura#Dispositivo_de_ensamble_(Bloques)": "ok",
    "dispositivo_con_seguros_completos#Dispositivo_de_ensamble_(Bloques)": "ok",
    "dispositivo_con_palancas_completas#Dispositivo_de_ensamble_(Bloques)": "ok",
    "dispositivo_sin_golpes_o_rotos#Dispositivo_de_ensamble_(Bloques)": "ok",
    "identificado_correctamente#Dispositivo_de_ensamble_(Bloques)": "ok",
    "dispositivo_correcto_seg\u00fan_n\u00famero_de_parte#Gage_final": "ok",
    "dispositivo_limpio_sin_manchas_de_pintura#Gage_final": "ok",
    "dispositivo_con_seguros_completos#Gage_final": "ok",
    "dispositivo_con_palancas_completas#Gage_final": "ok",
    "dispositivo_sin_golpes_o_rotos#Gage_final": "ok",
    "identificado_correctamente#Gage_final": "ok",
    "correctamente_identificada#Pieza_master": "ok",
    "fecha_de_vencimiento_sin_caducar#Pieza_master": "ok",
    "colocada_en_gage_final_o_colgada_en_la_mesa_de_manera_f\u00e1cil_de_identificar#Pieza_master": "ok",
    "instrucciones_de_trabajo#Documentaci\u00f3n_posteada": "ok",
    "opl#Documentaci\u00f3n_posteada": "ok",
    "alertas_de_calidad#Documentaci\u00f3n_posteada": "ok",
    "hoja_de_par\u00e1metros#Documentaci\u00f3n_posteada": "ok",
    "cat\u00e1logo_de_defectos#Documentaci\u00f3n_posteada": "ok",
    "c\u00f3digo_de_defectos#Documentaci\u00f3n_posteada": "ok",
    "para_marcaje_de_piezas_y_scrap#Plumones": "ok",
    "identifica_correctamente#Materia_prima": "ok",
    "liberada_por_calidad#Materia_prima": "ok",
    "ubicada_correctamente_en_el_rack#Materia_prima": "ok",
    "sin_defectos#Materia_prima": "ok",
    "limpio#Equipo_vac\u00edo": "ok",
    "sin_da\u00f1os#Equipo_vac\u00edo": "ok",
    "correctos#Equipo_vac\u00edo": "ok",
    "tipo": "Inicio"
}
```

Lo que quiero saber es como exportar esos datos en una hoja de calculo usando la libreria PHPSpreedSheet.
Ya hice las conexiones y todo necesarias en MySql y PHP. pero me exporta la hoja de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podría exportar bien esos datos para trabajar mejor con ellos. Teniendo en cuenta que todos los reportes se generan con la misma estructura en JSON.
Adjunto codigo de PHPSpreedsheet para que puedan darse una idea.

CONSULTA EN PHP PARA EXTRAER LOS DATOS.

```
$sql = ("SELECT resultados_prueba.*, Pieza.num_pieza, Prueba.nombre, Empleado.nombres, Empleado.num_nomina FROM resultados_prueba 
JOIN Prueba 
JOIN Empleado 
JOIN Pieza ON resultados_prueba.id_prueba=prueba.id 
AND resultados_prueba.id_empleado = Empleado.id 
AND Pieza.id = resultados_prueba.id_pieza WHERE resultados_prueba.id = '$reporte' ");
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

$hojaActiva->setCellValue('A1', 'ID');
$hojaActiva->setCellValue('B1', 'ID EMPLEADO');
$hojaActiva->setCellValue('C1', 'ID PRUEBA');
$hojaActiva->setCellValue('D1', 'ID PIEZA');
$hojaActiva->setCellValue('E1', 'FECHA');
$hojaActiva->setCellValue('F1', 'TURNO');
$hojaActiva->setCellValue('G1', 'NUMERO DE PIEZA');
$hojaActiva->setCellValue('H1', 'NOMBRE DE PIEZA');
$hojaActiva->setCellValue('I1', 'NOMBRES Y APELLIDOS');
$hojaActiva->setCellValue('J1', 'NUMERO DE NOMINA');

$hojaActiva->setCellValue('k1', 'RESULTADOS');

$fila = 2;

while ($rows = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('A' . $fila, $rows['id']);
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('B' . $fila, $rows['id_empleado']);
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('C' . $fila, $rows['id_prueba']);
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('D' . $fila, $rows['id_pieza']);
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('E' . $fila, $rows['fecha']);
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('F' . $fila, $rows['turno']);

    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('G' . $fila, $rows['num_pieza']);
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('H' . $fila, $rows['nombre']);
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('I' . $fila, $rows['nombres']);
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('J' . $fila, $rows['num_nomina']);

    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('K' . $fila, ($rows['resultados']));


    $fila++;


}
```

Asi se tendrian que observar los datos exportados en la hoja de calculo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

para acceder a tus datos del json, debes usar [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), esto lo harias dentro de tu while, quedando de esta manera

```
while ($rows = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
$myArray[] = $row;

$resultadosJson =  json_decode($myArray);
}
```

y con el resultado del json, accedes a los campos, quedando de esta manera

```
    while ($rows = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    $myArray[] = $row;
    
    $resultadosJson =  json_decode($myArray);
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('A' . $fila, $resultadosJson['id']);
 }
```

igualmente te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta, y pones la consulta de tu base de datos, porque estas haciendo un `SELECT resultados_prueba.*,`, esto esta mal, porque seleccionas los resultados de prueba, y posteriormente el resto, es como si hicieras nuevamente un `select * from`, no tiene sentido hacerlo de esa manera, porque al final estas mostrando todos los demas campos, que son estos `Pieza.num_pieza, Prueba.nombre, Empleado.nombres, Empleado.num_nomina`, te recomiendo que solo selecciones los campos que necesitas, mas o menos tu consulta quede de esta manera

```
SELECT resultados_prueba, Pieza.num_pieza, Prueba.nombre, Empleado.nombres, Empleado.num_nomina FROM resultados_prueba
```

igualmente en tu JSON no veo ningun Id, para que puedas acceder a el,
entonces el JSON que te mostre podria estar mal, el JSON que muestras deberia ser de esta manera

```
$hojaActiva->setCellValue('A' . $fila, $resultadosJson['dispositivo_correcto_seg\u00fan_n\u00famero_de_parte#Dispositivo_de_ensamble_(Bloques)']);
```